# Download a file to a google driver folder using selenium in heroku

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-drive-api, bots

Can i use the url to a google drive folder as a download_path in selenium
for instance like this .Heroku error says file not found

```
 mudopy.download_path(r"https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IPNuefeIXXCKm8Xxm3u1ekltxTF3dCT0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code of `mudopy` module, it saves the downloaded file into a local directory. So you can later upload that file to a google drive. Not sure if heroku allows to store something locally.
Moreover, the function `mudopy.download_path` does not download anything yet, but only creates a local file that stores the path to the folder where you want to save the downloaded files. And looks like Heroku does't even permit creating this file.